# Why is BeautifulSoup not finding a specific class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to try and scrape one of a webpage.
I can find all other elements successfully but somehow am unable to find a way to locate the chart at the top (under Focus --> Service Lines)

I tired below code but it simply returns an empty result set on find_all() -

```
    def get_company_info(self, url):
        self.sendRequest('https://clutch.co/profile/nuro-marketing')
        result = self.soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "chartAreaContainer"})
```

The output is [] in this case where as I can clearly see class while inspecting in Chrome.

[image]

All I want is to get the percentage of each 4 item in the bar graph. For example - Marketing Strategy 50%, Advertising 20%, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked that the tag is actually in the HTML, and not being generated after loading in the browser by JavaScript?

Comment: I can see it in the html source after loading (using Inspect element). Not sure how to determine if it was loaded through Javascript.

Comment: You probably need to work through a tutorial on web scraping then. But quickly: If you VIew Source in the browser, it should show the original source. Or if, inside that `send_request` method, you `print` the response text. Or if you use th `curl` or `wget` command-line tool.

Comment: (in your case, the class is actually loaded by JS)

Comment: @PRMoureu I see. I know this can be achieved easily through selenium but its slow. Can this be done in any way through web scraping?

Comment: Contents within chartAreaContainer are generated after loading by JS. You'll need to get help with Selenium for scraping contents. If you are looking to scrape contents of HighCharts / AmCharts, you could use this web service - https://github.com/PruthviKumarBK/chart_data_extractor PS: I'm the author of this micro-service. This is not a blatant advertisement. It helps you with examples of scraping dynamically generated contents.